# compare and compute every and the absolute difference of 2 files in awk

Tags: awk, compare, set-difference

I would like to ask how to compare and compute the difference between 2 files with **awk**

file1.txt

```
orange 30  
banana 25  
apple 30  
pear 35
```

file2.txt

```
orange 25  
apple 32  
jackfruit 15  
pear 40  
pineapple 20
```

The output should be the difference (and absolute values) between the two and stored in

file3.txt:

```
orange 5  
banana 25  
apple 2  
pear 5  
jackfruit 15  
pineapple 20
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

this one-liner should work:

```
 awk '$1 in a{a[$1]=sqrt((a[$1]-$2)^2);next}{a[$1]=$2}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file1 file2
```

with your example:

```
kent$  head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
orange 30  
banana 25  
apple 30  
pear 35

==> file2 <==
orange 25  
apple 32  
jackfruit 15  
pear 40  
pineapple 20 

kent$  awk '$1 in a{a[$1]=sqrt((a[$1]-$2)^2);next}{a[$1]=$2}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file1 file2
orange 5
jackfruit 15
apple 2
pineapple 20
pear 5
banana 25
```

Comment: Squaring and taking the square root is overkill for getting the absolute value and not the best approach numerically.

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
$ awk '{x=a[$1]-$2;a[$1]=(x<0.0)?-x:x}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file1 file2
orange 5
jackfruit 15
apple 2
pineapple 20
pear 5
banana 25
```

Comment: @Nate my pleasure. Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. This will show the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if (a[$1] == "")
         a[$1] = $2;
       else
       {
         if ((a[$1] - $2) < 0)
        a[$1] = $2 - a[$1];
         else
        a[$1] = a[$1] - $2;
       }
    } END { for (e in a) { print e, a[e] }}' file1.txt file2.txt
```